# in drupal 7 's view, how to comment without redirecting to content type page?

Tags: views, comments, redirection

I make a view for a specific content type, the path of content type and the path of the view are different. Now I put a form into the view, in order to comment on that content type. However whenever I comment on the view page, the view page will redirect to the path of content type, so the question is how can I comment without redirecting to the content page but staying on the view's page, perhaps working with ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [Ajax comments](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module you can use to post comments without refresh and [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1447792) shows how to combine it with views.